# Call again function with new parameters from hook. C++, Assembly, Ollydbg

Tags: c++, assembly, hook, call, reverse-engineering

I am developing an online game. I have full source code for the server, but the game client I am using is closed-source that requires some reverse engineering. I am trying to properly call the `draw_rectangle` function. In the image below you can see screenshot from OLLY.

There are functions:

DRAW_BLACK_BAR(black frame for health bar),

DRAW_COLORED_BAR(The health inside),

DRAW_NICK(already hooked)

[image]

the CALL DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+14] always points to 0x4EB2F0

So the addres contains that function in debugger:

[image]

As you can see there are parameters on the stack such as Surface_id, position, size, color, and pointer to creature.

This is my hook:

```
superHook(dwHandle, 0x4C8C28, (unsigned int)newFunc); //instead of call print rectangle func for colored bar

void superHook(HANDLE dwHandle, int adr, unsigned int targetFunction)
{
    //its not normal CALL ADDR which takes 5 bytes (E8 + 4x bytes for address)
    //It is CALL DWORD PTR DS:[EDX+14] which takes 3bytes, so we will take more space
    //and we will rebuild the function


    // jmp to address +2x nop
    BYTE bytes[7] = { 0xE9, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x90, 0x90};
    DWORD targetAddr = targetFunction - adr - 5;
    *(DWORD*)(bytes + 1) = targetAddr;
    WriteProcessMemory(dwHandle, (void *)adr, bytes, 7, NULL);
}

void newFunc()
{
    //Rebuild the function (Earsed commands to be able to put JMP address)
    __asm {
            MOV ECX, DWORD PTR SS : [EBP - 0x18]
            PUSH ESI
    }

    //Here I can access all the registers and stack before CALL will be executed


    //call draw rectangle
    __asm {
            CALL DWORD PTR DS : [EDX + 0x14]//always call 0x4EB2F0?
    }


    //go back
    __asm {
        PUSH 0x4C8C2F
            RET
    }

}
```

It works fine, as I can access the parameters on the stack and modify them (Change color,size, location etc). However, I would like to be able to create another rectangle, for example next one with another color and position. I tried a lot of combinations of setting up the new stack with parameters calling the func and then calling it again with original ones but I always end up with a client crash.

Here's an one of example of my attempt to create new call + restoring old one
https://pastebin.com/RUmaPGya (pastebin to not make this post too long)

Comment: line 30 should be deleted as `[ebp]` is just the saved `ebp` you pushed earlier.  Certainly not there on the original stack. Also line 36 should be `add` not `sub` and the value should be adjusted too. Quite ironic that you saved `edi`, `ecx` and `ebx` (none of which you need) but you didn't save `edx` which is obviously needed for `call [edx+0x14]`.

Comment: Its just a sample of combinations I tried. I did it also with all registers. The question is the method I am trying to do it is correct? Should I care about only about the stack before making call or registers too?

Comment: Registers are not used to pass input arguments in standard calling conventions.

Comment: I tried also with stack only. Game crashed too. As far I know the game client is using cdecl convention instead of stdcall. I wonder why it crashes then. The only non-constant param is creature pointer, but thats why I hook that function to get the right one, the rest of params should be able to create unique rectangle.